# Inno Setup Directory Exists

Tags: directory, inno-setup, pascal

I am trying to check in inno setup if a directory exists and i would like to do so manually respectively programmatically.
The Setup I am creating in Inno setup is an update.
Here comes the tricky part, the initial setup uses a C# application to install 
all the files on the disc because the setup is different for every customer.
I want to check now which directories are installed, because by that i know what i have to update.
My question is:
How do i determine in Inno setup if a directory exists or how do i determine which subdirectorys a directory has

And as always Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about [`DirExists` function](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_direxists.htm)? Example: `if DirExists(ExpandConstant('{userdocs}\Games\My Game')) then //action...`

Comment: Okay that was easy ... why haven't i found that.okay thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about [`DirExists` function](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_direxists.htm)?

You can use it as `Check` or other kind of function - whatever you need.

Example in code:

```
if DirExists(ExpandConstant('{userdocs}\Games\My Game')) then 
//action, Result := True, etc...
```